# MVC3 Razor using Html.BeginForm problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is probably a simple thing, but ive got the following code:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <p>
            ...
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

And it keeps complaining that the starting { bracket must be followed by a end } bracket, but its there, and all code examples doing this sort of stuff show this as the way to do it, so im a bit baffled as to why it doesn't work...

Comment: Tried removing the <p> tags and its still dying on me:  Parser Error Message: The using block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Probably there is an error in the code within the `<p>` and `</p>` tags.

Try commenting it out and see what the result is:

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <p>
                    @*  = Server side comment out.
                    ....
                    *@
        </p>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Being an idiot, it seems there was an unclosed quotation mark on a child element (value="Submit), which seemed to have been causing the issues :(

Comment: You're not an idiot just for that. That would mean I'm an idiot everyday. Uh-oh...

Comment: Yes even something as simple as a missing end div tag </div> could cause this. Just mentioning this since everyone is using bootstrap today and this could easily be the cause if you moved a form end brace up in your html cod.e

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me this way:

```
  @{ using (Html.BeginForm(...))
     {
      <p>
      Content here
      </p>
     }
  }
```

The problem is that using is a statement, not an expression, so `@csharpexpression` won't work. For statements, the razor syntax is to use `@{csharpstatement}`. But the using statement includes its own pair of curly braces, so it gets a little twisted like `@{ using(...) { ... } }`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing a closing div which caused a similar error.

Error Code:

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div><p>
                @*  = Server side comment out.
                ....
                *@
    </p>
}
</div>
```

Resolved:

```
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div><p>
                @*  = Server side comment out.
                ....
                *@
    </p></div>
}
</div>
```