# Why does normal markup inside an @Using Html.BeginForm need an @?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

related: [MVC3 Razor using Html.BeginForm problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990717/mvc3-razor-using-html-beginform-problem)

When I make an HTML form for MVC 3/VB with the Razor engine, I would expect to be able to do it like this:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")
    <fieldset>
        @* Other form code and values *@
    </fieldset>
End Using
```

But if I do that I get "BC32035: Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement."  I need to add an @ character before the opening  tag to avoid this error.  Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Razor with C#, what you describe is possible, because parser can determine the transition from code to markup because of the explicit '<' characters in html is not a valid C# token. VB.NET supports inline XML directly in code, so the Razor parser cannot determine that you have transitioned back to markup, so you have to be more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

I believe in Razor beginform should be like this, ie with curly braces:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @* Other code here *@
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't use VB.NET, but I think you should do this:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")
    @:<fieldset>
        @* Other form code and values *@
    @:</fieldset>
End Using
```

With VB.NET's first-class supports for XML, it treats tags as XML, hence it treats fieldset(any HTML tags for that matter) as XML too; and XML as being part of language of VB.NET, it will run counter to Razor's parser

A quick trip on VS2010 using ASP.NET MVC for VB.NET, this would suffice:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")
    @<fieldset>
        @* Other form code and values *@
    </fieldset>
End Using
```

VB.NET's language literal XML support run afoul of Razor's parser, just prevent it with adding extra `@` or `@:`

Comment: What does the extra @ or @: do in that code?  Is it some kind of escape character?

Comment: More or less yes. It signals razor that you are escaping from programming language's (e.g. C#, VB.NET) syntax. There's no extra nudging needed for C#, as the symbol `<` is not used by it, and as such, Razor can also use the `<` as an *escaper* for C#; there's no such privilege in VB.NET, in VB.NET, anything that starts with `<` is an XML literal, so for this kind of scenario, you need to use Razor's `@` to escape the VB.NET's syntax

Comment: Another example of Razor's nuance: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2011/08/razor-tag-nuances.html

Answer (score 1):

For **multi-line support**, as pointed out in [Using in Razor VB.net MVC not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16414271/1366033), you can use `@<text>...</text>` to switch back to "text mode" and output html like this:

```vb
@Using Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")
    @<text>
      <fieldset>
        * Other form code and values *
      </fieldset>
    </text>
End Using
```