# Using in Razor VB.net MVC not work as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I'm not sure why this syntax complain error "Enter is not declared. May be inaccessible due to protection level" and must put "@html(" to get rid the error.

This block complain error

```
   @Using (Html.BeginForm("GetUser", "UserProfile", FormMethod.Post))
      Enter User id :-  @Html.TextBox("UserId",Model)  -- This line must write in this way @Html("Enter User id :-")
      <input type="submit" value="Submit  data" />  --This line complain ">" expected"
   End Using
```

If rewrite the code in this way, the complain gone, but the output display "System.Web.MVC.Html" at the beginning like the image below

```
       @Html.BeginForm("GetUser", "UserProfile", FormMethod.Post)
       Enter User id :-   @Html.TextBox("UserId",Model) 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit  data" />
```

[image]

hi nemesv if Use `@<Text>`
,it's complain this -->"Using must end with End Using."
[image]

Comment: You have forgot the close the `@<text>` see in my example I have: `@<text><input type="submit" value="Submit  data" /></text>` note the closing `</text>` at the end of the line.

Comment: Opppss! Too new in MVC. everything seem new to me, Thanks!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does normal markup inside an @Using Html.BeginForm need an @?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225394/why-does-normal-markup-inside-an-using-html-beginform-need-an)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are inside a `Using` block you are in "code mode" in Razor.

So you need to use the `@:` (for single line statements) or `@<text> .. </text>` (for multi line statements) to switch back to "text mode" and output html.

With using `@:`:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("GetUser", "UserProfile", FormMethod.Post))
      @:Enter User id :-  @Html.TextBox("UserId",Model)  
      @:<input type="submit" value="Submit  data" />
End Using
```

or with using `@<text>`:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm("GetUser", "UserProfile", FormMethod.Post))
      @<text>Enter User id :-</text>  @Html.TextBox("UserId",Model)  
      @<text><input type="submit" value="Submit  data" /></text>
End Using
```

See also the [Combining text, markup, and code in code blocks](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/asp-net-web-pages-visual-basic) section for further info.

Comment: Is the `@` in front of `<text>` a VB thing? I know it's not needed it C#

Comment: @mattytommo yes the `@<text>` is a VB only thing in C# you only need `<text>`

Comment: i still got this error : '>' expected when run in the browser. at this line @:<input type="submit" value="Submit  data" /> but it's ok on design time and also @<text> not working for me. I'm using vs 2012. .net 4.5

Comment: @tsohtan If I copy the code form my answer to a newly created MVC3 or MVC4 project it is working fine. There is still something in your view code which makes it not working. Please double check that you are using the correct syntax or update your question with your actual view code.

Comment: Ah.... sorry somehow the "View Page Inspector" cache it or something wrong, i rebuild it and run on browser is Worked!!!.Thanks! I'm using mvc4. But i still cant use @<text>

Comment: If the `@<text>` is not working (can be it also some caching issues?) you should update your post with an example how you try to use the `@<text>` maybe I can help.