# VB syntax in razor view page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

Here is my MVC View page VB code, that ViewData("Maximum exceed") is passed from controller. That is, if ViewData("Maximum exceed") is true, it will render a row with label control. Is there anything wrong with my VB syntax? How can I put VB condition in the View page?

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm())
@<table>  

     @If ViewData("IsMaximumExceed") Then
     <tr>
         <td colspan="3">
             @Html.Label(
                 Sub(settings)
                     settings.AssociatedControlName = "MaximumExceed"
                     settings.Text = "Maximum Exceed"                                                               
                 End Sub).GetHtml()
         </td>
     <tr>
</table>
End Using
```

Comment: What is the problem? It looks okay to me... though note that VB is not supported by ASP.NET Core (including Razor) so you should transition to C# as soon as possible.

Comment: Note that in ASP.NET MVC there are no "Controls" - the `Html.Label` is a "HTML Helper" which renders HTML directly in a stateless manner.

Comment: I got VB syntax error on <tr><td> element in razor view, so what's wrong is the syntax?

Comment: I have modified the code above, wondering what's wrong with VB syntax.

Comment: Well, you're missing an `End If`, for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the arguments to `Label(HtmlHelper, String, String)` the wrong way around. The first string parameter is the `expression`, the second string parameter is the `labelText`.

Your `If ViewData("Maximum exceed")` checks to see if there's a dictionary member with key `"Maximum exceed"` but the `expression` value is `"MaximumExceed"` - they don't match.

That said, you should prefer a strongly-typed "view model" object instead of using the untyped `ViewData` or `ViewBag` objects.

```
Public Class MyPageViewModel

    Public MaximumExceeded As Boolean

End Class

...

Public Function MyControllerAction() As ActionResult 

    Dim viewModel As New MyPageViewModel
    viewModel.MaximumExceeded = True
    Return Me.View( viewModel )

End Sub

...

@Model MyPageViewModel

@If Model.MaximumExceeded Then

    @Html.Label( NameOf(Model.MaximumExceeded), "Maximum exceeded" )

End If
```

Note my use of the `NameOf` operator to get the string name of the property. Or better yet, use `Html.LabelFor`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I will apply the expression in the razor view.

Comment: However I would like to display Label control in a table row, how can I put VB syntax condition in the view?

Comment: <table>
    @If ViewData("Maximum exceed") Then
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    @Html.Label( NameOf(Model.MaximumExceeded), "Maximum       exceed")
    </td>
    </tr>
    End If

Comment: I have modified the code above, wondering what's wrong with VB syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Since `@Using (Html.BeginForm())` statement begins a form in "code block mode", in VB.NET context you need to set "text mode" either using `@:` (single line operator), `@<text>...</text>` (single or multiple line mode) or simply `@` followed with HTML block element:

```
' Using @:
@Using (Html.BeginForm())
@:<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 800px; height:100px;">
    <!-- inner table -->
@:</table>
End Using

' Using @<text>...</text>
@Using (Html.BeginForm())
@<text><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 800px; height:100px;">
       <!-- inner table -->
 </table></text>
End Using

'Using @<tag>...</tag>
@Using (Html.BeginForm())
    @<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 800px; height:100px;">
           <!-- inner table -->
    </table>
End Using
```

The reason behind usage of operators to enclose HTML tags is that VB.NET allows inline XML elements by applying "text mode" inside "code block mode" which C# doesn't have that feature (see [Razor syntax for VB.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-vb#BM_CombiningTextMarkupAndCode)).

Hence, the provided sample in question should be modified like this, using `@` before `<tr>` tag to create HTML block element under `If` code block:

```
@Using (Html.BeginForm())
@<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 800px; height:100px;">  
 @If ViewData("IsGroupVessel") Then
 @<tr>
      <td colspan="3">
      @Html.DevExpress().Label(Sub(settings)
            settings.AssociatedControlName = "GroupBooking"
            settings.Text = "Maximum Exceeded"                                                               
       End Sub).GetHtml()
      </td>
  </tr>
  End If
 </table>
End Using
```

As @Dai stated in his answer, I also prefers usage of a strongly-typed "view model" with properties instead passing `ViewBag` or `ViewData`, hence the modified code is shown below:

**Model**

```
Public Class ViewModel
   Public Property IsExceeded As Boolean
   ' other models
End Class
```

**Controller**

```
Public Function ActionMethod() As ActionResult
   Dim model As New ViewModel
   ' other logic
   model.IsExceeded = True
   ' other logic
   Return Me.View(model)
End Function
```

**View**

```
@ModelType ViewModel

@Using (Html.BeginForm())
@<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 800px; height:100px;">
 @If Model.IsExceeded Then
 @<tr>
      <td colspan="3">
      @Html.DevExpress().Label(Sub(settings)
          settings.AssociatedControlName = "GroupBooking"
          settings.Text = "Maximum Exceeded"                                                               
      End Sub).GetHtml()
      </td>
  </tr>
  End If
  </table>
End Using
```

Related issues:

[Razor View Engine Quirks in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169340/razor-view-engine-quirks-in-vb-net)

[Using in Razor VB.net MVC not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414271/using-in-razor-vb-net-mvc-not-work-as-expected)

Comment: I got it, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Julia Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) an answer which solved your problem by clicking the check mark besides that answer, indicating that you've already found the solution. There is no obligation to do so.