# ASP MVC 3 Get hiddenfield value of specific item in foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, html-helper

I currently have this code:

```
foreach (var item in Model.LstBagels)
            {

                    @Html.Hidden("txtId", item.BagelId)
                    <div id="bagel">                     
                        <div id="bagel-info">                  
                            <div id="bagel-image">
                                <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Resources/Images/{0}.jpg", item.Image))" alt="" />
                            </div> 

                            @if (@BestelBagels.Resources.Views.Index.IndexStrings.Name == "Name")
                            {
                                <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)<br /></h2>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.NameFr)<br /></h2>
                            }
```

```
<input class="button widthorder" type="submit" name="BtnOrder" value="@BestelBagels.Resources.Views.Index.IndexStrings.Bestellen"/>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
```

And when press my button I always Receive the first Id from all items, or the list of all the items.
But how can I receive the Id that i submit for?
My txtId is always the first Id from my itemsource.

Greets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where is the button?

Why don't you warp every div in form using the [Form HtmlHelpers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410596%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990717/mvc3-razor-using-html-beginform-problem):

```
foreach (var item in Model.LstBagels)
            {
 @using (Html.BeginForm('ActionName', 'ContollerName', FormMethod.Post) {
                    @Html.Hidden("txtId", item.BagelId)
                    <div id="bagel">                     
                        <div id="bagel-info">                  
                            <div id="bagel-image">
                                <img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Resources/Images/{0}.jpg", item.Image))" alt="" />
                            </div> 

                            @if (@BestelBagels.Resources.Views.Index.IndexStrings.Name == "Name")
                            {
                                <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)<br /></h2>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.NameFr)<br /></h2>
                            }
<input class="button widthorder" type="submit" name="BtnOrder" value="@BestelBagels.Resources.Views.Index.IndexStrings.Bestellen"/>
                        </div>
```

}

if you don't care to much about non-js browser and you action accepts GET, you can skip the form use and simply build your action button:

```
<input class="button widthorder" type="button" name="BtnOrder" onClick="window.location='@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName"   , new { txtId= item.BagelId })'" value="@BestelBagels.Resources.Views.Index.IndexStrings.Bestellen"/>
```

Comment: Added my button, my bad. What do u mean by warp every div in form?